# javax.xml.bind.annotation.xmlseealso cannot be resolved

Tags: java, web-services, soap

In my java Webservice project

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;    
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;
```

these statements are giving syntax error

Cannote be resolved.

I have added the dependent jar
javax.servlet.jar

```
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
```

But the same setup with same jar is not throwing error in another manchine.

Please help to resolve.

Comment: What you mean by machine? You mean different tomcat server?

Comment: javax.servlet.jar is part of your tomcat lib already and you don't need to add it explicitly.

Comment: I mean on some other laptop